# Avoid doing same calculation multiple times inside a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where i am repeating calculations like

```
DROP PROCEDURE sp_alters;
DELIMITER $$


CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    PROCEDURE `sp_alters`()
    /*LANGUAGE SQL
    | [NOT] DETERMINISTIC
    | { CONTAINS SQL | NO SQL | READS SQL DATA | MODIFIES SQL DATA }
    | SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }
    | COMMENT 'string'*/
    BEGIN
SELECT  
   `fn_getDiscount`(`t_orderitem`.`a_orderitemid`,`t_orderitem`.`a_quantity`)  AS `discount`,

    fn_getnewvalues(`fn_getDiscount`(`t_orderitem`.`a_orderitemid`,`t_orderitem`.`a_quantity`),a_orderitemid) as newvalue

FROM t_orderitem;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here you see that i am calling fn_getDiscount 2 times inside same stored procedure. So i want to avoid it. Can i store into a variable and use it?

Comment: Can you post here the whole stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

You have to *prepare* the sentence and then reuse it.

```
SET @your_variable = "this is some text you can repeat";
SET @your_query=CONCAT("
INSERT INTO something
", @some_variable,"
WHERE other_things");

PREPARE stmt FROM @your_query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

This is the basic structure from which you can work and reuse the way you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you had shown the complete statement and at least the header of the procedure, but looking at what you have presented *as* code appears to be snippets from code - and fn_getDiscount appears to be a function not a procedure.

Preparing the statement only avoids having to parse the statement each time it is referenced - it does not avoid the overhead of executing the statement.

Although, IIRC, MySQL does not currently implement this, any funcion declared as DETERMINISTIC (i.e. will always produce the same output for a given set of inputs without side effects) is cacheable - this may change in future, hence it would be a good idea to add it.

If the function is determinstic then you can avoid calling it multiple times by using a sub-query:

```
SELECT func_result
FROM (SELECT expensive_function(your_columns...) AS func_result
      FROM your_table
      WHERE your_column_a BETWEEN 1 AND 100) AS ilv
WHERE func_result > 50;
```

Within a procedure of function, you can call other functions and store the result in a variable - that's the main reason for using stored functions / procedures.

Comment: I have to use it to calculate another column value.